# Were bookshops 'common' in the late 19th century, and how did they differ from modern ones?

Tags: 19th-century, britain, book, victorian

I've been reading a little bit about Victorian publishing bit I'm struggling to get a feel for how common and how similar Victorian bookstores in London would be.

[This](https://writersinspire.org/content/victorian-publishing-history) is all I've read. It sounds like by about 1890 all you have of fiction in shops are thin serials, and in fact there's more libraries than shops. Is that true?

How's common would a Victorian bookshop be?  Would they stock modern size novels,  or would they be more for scientific literature?

Comment: What's your definition of 'common'? What metric would you like to see?

Comment: @deerhunter more a comparison to today's bookshops. I'm not interested in exact quantities.

Comment: The total population today is much larger than 1890, and the percentage of the population that can afford to buy and read books is much larger. The cost of books has fallen precipitously.   On the other hand, there were no Victorian chain bookstores.  "common" is a subjective term, and undermines your question, but prima facia bookstores are more common today than they were then.  (especially if you ignore the implosion of bookstores in the past 10 years.)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace 'Prima Facia'?

Comment: Sorry - [prima facie](http://dictionary.law.com/default.aspx?selected=1598), which is Latin for "I arrived at this conclusion through reasoning, and I'm too lazy and feckless to research the answer or even to bother to spell it correctly"

Comment: Not an answer, but in the UK the answer would be a resounding "No".  Books were expensive, even  the middle-classes patronised circulating libraries, rather than bookshops. Also, books were usually published in weekly editions - rather like the "Build your own starship" part works of today. Foyles, one of the UK 's most famous bookshops, didn't open until the beginning of the 20th century - 1903, I  think, but like @MarkCWallace I'm too lazy to check!

Comment: @thehonrose then why should I bother asking here if the 'experts' are to lazy to answer questions?

Comment: @Pureferret  1) I'm not an "expert".  2) I said it wasn't an answer.  3) It was  a joke!

Comment: @thehonrose you're the second person who's implied they know where to look,  so you're clearly more qualified than I am to answer. If you know where to look I'll do the research and self-answer.

Comment: @Pureferret  Well, I just looked up some old-established UK bookshops - Foyles, Blackwells, WHSmith - etc and checked their founding dates.   As for the rest, I simply know from previous study that Victorian novels were serialised - Dickens was - either in single volumes or in journals like Dickens' *Household Words*.   I'm afraid I can't be specific, bit out of date on 19th century history, but I would suggest any reasonable social history of the period would be the place to start.

Comment: Two of the most famous bookstore chains in Britain are Blackwells (based in Oxford) and Foyles (based in London). The former was founded in 1879 and the latter in 1903. both have Wikipedia entries which tell you about their histories.

Comment: @ws2 but it's one thing to look at the individual famous ones, it's another to look at all the small ones that sprung up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bookshops were certainly ***becoming* more common** in Victorian England. In fact, the entire printed world exploded in the 19th century. Most of it was concentrated in London, which by 1860 housed 812 booksellers, of whom 211 were also publishers.<sup>**1**</sup> Edinburgh, the Scottish capital, was home to another 120 booksellers, with 30 also publishing. In contrast, the *[Universal British Directory](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=UQwHAAAAQAAJ&redir_esc=y)* listed only 988 booksellers *for the entire country* at the end of the 18th century.<sup>**2**</sup>

At the same time, bookstores still had a long way to go. By the outbreak of the [Second World War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II), there was ***four to five thousand*** booksellers operating within Great Britain.<sup>**3**</sup> From one perspective then, bookstores were not "common" in Victorian Britain, at least not to the same extent that they would become in the 20th century.

Nonetheless, by the later 19th century bookshops had broken into the mass consumer market. Historically, books had been prohibitively costly to own. This was still true up in the early 19th century. Books were still a low volume business; booksellers did not maintain much stocks but instead treated assisting clients in acquiring specific books as a core business.<sup>**3**</sup> Even subscribers to private libraries, which were touted as a cheaper format for readers, were typically from the more prosperous elements of society.<sup>**4**</sup>

From the middle of the century onward, however, readerships spread far and wide. While improved literacy played a part, important gains in that area were reached by the 18th century. Instead, most of the credit should go to the mass availability of low cost books.<sup>**6**</sup> The [Industrial Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_Revolution) was yielding dividends, and technological innovations such as better papermaking and printing techniques drastically lowered the cost of printed publications.

Newspapers were the most widespread. With reduced publishing costs after the repeal of taxation on newspapers, they became affordable to even the lower class at merely a penny or two. Likewise, specialised periodicals catering to disparate tastes and demographic groups began to emerge.<sup>**4**</sup> Apart from writings targeting the likes of farmers or homemakers, family friendly works such as those of [Charles Dickens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Dickens) were also published in [periodicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodical_literature). These would often be read to the whole family by a literate member.

Periodical literature supplemented but **did *not* replace conventional books**; indeed books became more accessible than ever. In the second half of the century, book prices fell precipitously thanks to increased competition between booksellers at the retail level.<sup>**5**</sup> Decades of abortive attempts at price fixing finally broke down after 1852, and for the next few decades booksellers entered a period of intensive, unrestricted mutual undercutting.

The destructive price war depressed profit margins and bankrupted many merchants, but also meant late Victorian readers could expect a substantial discount on the cover price of books. By the time retailers and publishers finally cooperated to enact the price-fixing [Net Book Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_Book_Agreement) of 1899, books were being read by far more people than ever before.

---

[image]
<sup>(*Vickers Publisher, Holywell Street*. Artist unknown. [Holywell Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holywell_Street,_London) was a notorious centre for pornographic publications before it was demolished to widen [the Strand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strand,_London))</sup>

[image]
<sup>([Daunt Books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daunt_Books) on the [Marylebone High Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marylebone_High_Street). An bookstore chain that recently also began publishing. [Source](https://ekinura.wordpress.com/2013/03/31/daunt-books-marylebone/))</sup>

By the time of the late Victorian period, bookstores were already quite similar to contemporary ones. The intense price competition led to a diversification of a bookseller's business. Stationary, diaries, calendars, letters, art supplies, newspaper, periodicals, and [greeting cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeting_card) could all be found at in late 19th century bookstores.<sup>**4**</sup> In other words, much like what you would expect in a modern shop.

Like books, holiday greeting cards were originally priced as luxuries. Technical advances such as [lithography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithography) allowed cards to be mass produced cheaply, making them accessible to the common people by the end of the century.

---

**References**

<sub>**1.** "The Book Trade." *American Literary Gazette and Publishers' Circular* (1864) 1.</sub>
<sub>**2.** Dickinson, Harry Thomas, ed. *A Companion to Eighteenth-Century Britain.* John Wiley & Sons, 2008.</sub>
<sub>**3.** Levy, Hermann. *The Shops of Britain: a Study of Retail Distribution*. Routledge, 2013.</sub>
<sub>**4.** Graham, Kelley. *Gone to the Shops: Shopping in Victorian England.* Greenwood Publishing Group, 2008.</sub>
<sub>**5.** Daunton, Martin. *The Organisation of Knowledge in Victorian Britain.* Oxford University Press, 2005.</sub>
<sub>**6.** Perry, Karin. "Literacy and Technology: A Historical View." *Technological Tools for the Literacy Classroom* (2013)</sub>

Comment: This is everything I wanted and more

Comment: @Pureferret Glad it's useful :)

Comment: This deserves a hundred up votes.

Comment: @IanF1 13 and counting...