# Was there a particular area of Victorian London in which bookshops were concentrated?

Tags: 19th-century, england, book, victorian

I see that there were many booksellers in Victorian London. Was there a particular area that hosted "respectable bookshops", in the manner that Petticoat Lane was a centre for Victorian clothing?

Comment: How does a "respectable" bookshop differ from any other kind?

Comment: @SteveBird The bookshops in [Holywell Street](http://www.victorianlondon.org/districts/holywellstreet.htm) were certainly not regarded as "respectable" at the time.

Comment: You might also find the references at the end of [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/26739/24858) by @Semaphore to another question about late 19th century bookshops useful.

Answer (score 16):

This [page on London during the Victorian era](http://www.avictorian.com/london_streets.html) offers (emphasis mine):

> Further, there are the streets and districts for particular trades, as Long Acre, where the carriage-makers abound; and Lombard Street, where the bankers love to congregate; and Clerkenwell, the district for the watch-makers; and Hatton Garden for the Italian glass-blowers; and the Borough for the hatters; Bermondsey for the tanners; Lambeth for the potters; and Spitalflelds for weavers; and Catherine Street for the newsvendors; and **Paternoster Row for the booksellers**; and the New Road for the zinc-workers: and Lower Thames Street for the merchants in oranges and foreign fruits; and Mincing Lane for the wholesale grocers; and Holywell Street and Rosemary Lane for old clothes; and so on.

The footnote suggests it's a quote from a book named "The Great World of the London Streets" by Henry Mayhew, 1862. Googling yields a very similarly titled book, ["The Great World of London"](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/010460369) by the same author from around the same time (1856) that apparently ended up published under a slightly different title in 1862. The online book contains the above quote.

(The quote doesn't say it was a street where "respectable" bookshops were concentrated.)

Editing to add, courtesy of Steve Bird, that the wikipedia article on [Paternoster Row](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paternoster_Row) also offers that:

> In 1819 Paternoster Row was described as "almost synonymous" with the book trade.

Based on: A Pictorial and Descriptive Guide to London and Its Environs: With Two Large Section Plans of Central London... Ward, Lock & Company, Limited. 1819.

Comment: The geographical proximity of Paternoster Row to St Paul's Cathedral is a pretty good clue that the businesses located there were "respectable" - though some of their publications were certainly "scurrilous!" The centre of the London pornographic book trade was Holywell Street, off the Strand. http://londonist.com/2016/06/how-london-s-victorians-bought-their-porn. https://publicdomainreview.org/2016/06/29/the-secret-history-of-holywell-street-home-to-victorian-londons-dirty-book-trade/

Comment: Clerkenwell was also a centre for printing.

Comment: Very useful. I will follow up on Mayhew et al